# is there a secured "mkdir()" similar function in c?

Tags: c

Is there a secured way to get a "path string" from a user, generate it
within a root directory, while avoiding directory traversal?
some kind of a "secured mkdir()".

lets say, root directory is-> "c:/test"
avoid a situation that a user types -> "c:/test/../windows/abc.exe"
thank you very much.

Comment: +1 Seeing all the security issues we have today, there should be one.

Comment: The problem you've got here is deciding which folders are off limits, the '..' relative path is acceptable and safe in many situations. This is more an issue for administrators to limit access to system folders (which you can do in Windows too!). I guess this problem started with early versions of windows having users set up as administrators by default.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no. You will need to parse the path provided and sanitize it yourself (which is good practice anyway, even if operating within a secured environment).

If you were running under *nix, I would advise the use of a chroot (or equivalent) to limit file system access, unfortunately windows does not support that (except arguably as part of managed windows 8 apps).

Assuming you are going to sanitize it yourself, don't forget that as well as the '..\' notation, there are also junction points to consider (the rarely used ntfs implementation of symlinks).

Comment: Even better, start an OSS project which collects such "innocent" library functions and supplies safe ones.